# Getting difference between two versions of Shapefile using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, fields-attributes

I have two shapefiles that are the same in terms of the type of information they contain (same attribute fields).  One is essentially an updated version of the other, so the newer version contains all the data of the earlier version plus more.

Each data entry has a unique id field. I am looking for a way to essentially 'subtract' the older shapefile from the newer one.  This cannot be a spatial operation, it must be based on the attributes. I use primarily OGR and QGIS.

Any ideas on how to do something like this?

Comment: My approach thus far is to merge the two shapefiles into one, then use a ogr2ogr with a sql query to look for distinct ids.  While this sort of works, I don't get a shapefile output, but just a dbf file containing the only the distinct ids:

ogr2ogr -sql "select distinct id from '2008_archiveMerge'" 2008_archiveMerge_filter.shp 2008_archiveMerge.shp

Replacing the 'id' with a '*' fails though.

Comment: Are wanting to know what is different?

Comment: I am looking for a shapefile containing the entries unique to the newer data.

Comment: Unique new records and/or old records with new attributes?

Comment: Just the new records - the old records exist in the new file and are (or should be) exact copies - these attributes should not have changed.  

So, it would be get take all the entries in the old file (identified by the unique 'id' of each entry), find the same 'id's in the new file and remove those entries.

It seems more and more like I will have to script this, but it just seems that there should be a way to do this without a script.

Comment: Can't you just join (not spatially) the old data to the new data based on unique ID and keeping all records, then open up the attribute table and sort by an old data field? Any new data should have nulls in the join fields, so you can select them and do whatever - export to new set, set a new attribute, invert selection and delete, etc. I can think of exact steps and other ways to do this in Arc, but not so much QGIS.

Answer (score 5):

I assume a situation like below:

1. When we visited last week, there were only three (3) schools. (Layer `school_layer_1`)
2. However, we found five (5) schools this week. (Layer `school_layer_2`)

And we want to know which schools are newly built.

[image]

Then we can use a **Virtual Layer** to find out suspicious schools.

[image]

The SQL query is:

```
SELECT * FROM school_layer_2
WHERE id
IN (
    SELECT id FROM school_layer_2
    EXCEPT
    SELECT id FROM school_layer_1
   )
```

The produced Virtual Layer (green circles) is a point layer with the records of difference between `school_layer_1` and `school_layer_2`.

Answer (score 2):

There is a new tool which was added in QGIS 3.12 called ["Detect dataset changes"](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html?highlight=split%20vector%20layer#detect-dataset-changes-312) that does exactly what you want. It accepts any geometry type including point. The tool

> Compares two vector layers, and determines which features are
> unchanged, added or deleted between the two. It is designed for
> comparing two different versions of the same dataset.

Original point:

[image]

Modified point:

[image]

Changes happened:

[image]

Please refer to the help above for more detailed information.

Information in the changelog for QGIS 3.12: https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog312/#feature-add-new-algorithm-detect-dataset-changes

Answer (score -2):

Maybe Layers by Field QGIS Plugin could do what you need

[Layers by Field QGIS Plugin](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/layers_by_field/)